# Parametric equation of a circle given starting point.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, circles, parametric

Find the parametric equations of a circle with radius of $5$ where you start at point $(5,0)$ at $v=0$ and you travel clockwise with a period of $3$.

So, I know that I require to have a $x(v)$ and $y(v)$ answer.

So for $x(v)$, Since it starts at $5$, I figured the answer would be $x(v) = 5 + 5\cos()$ and for $y(v)$, since it starts at $0$, its simply $y(v) = 0 + 5 \sin()$. However, I am not too sure about what to enter in the parentheses.( I know that we would need $bv$, where $b$ is the coefficient to $v$). Since it says $3$ period, is it found like this?

$$3b = 2 \pi, \quad b = \frac{2}{3} \pi$$

And so, the answer for $x$ would be $x(v) = 5 + 5\cos(2/3\pi v)$ and for $y; y(v) = 5 \sin(2/3\pi v)$. My answers are wrong, could you explain where I went wrong. Thanks!

calculus

Comment: If the center of your circle lies at the origin, you don't want to be adding a 5 to your cosine term in the function for $ \ x \ $ (by putting it in there, what does that make the average value of $ \ x(v) \ $ ) ?

Comment: I don't quite get it, if it says that  "you start at point (5,0)" doesn't that mean that it doesn't start at the origin?

Comment: "Starting at $ \ (5, \ 0)  $ " means you are on the _circumference_ of the circle and tracing _along_ the circle.  The center of the circle is not the starting point.  Your equation for the $ \ x-$ coordinate will be $ \ x(v) \ = \ 0 \ + \ 5 \cos(\frac{2 \pi}{3}v) \ $ , just as you wrote for $ \ y(v) \ $ .  (What is the value of $ \ x( v) \ $ at $ \ v \ = \ 0 \ $ ? )  The numerical terms that you would add to the trigonometric terms in your parametric equations would be the coordinates for the circle's center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the period under control, so we will not deal with that. If we are travelling around the circle with centre the origin, and radius $r$, in mathematicians' favourite direction, counterclockwise, starting at $(r,0)$, then the parametric equation is of the shape $x=r\cos( kt)$, $y=r\sin(kt)$.

For travelling clockwise, replace $t$ by $-t$.  But $\cos(-kt)=\cos(kt)$ and $\sin(-kt)=-\sin(kt)$, so the parametric equation can be written as $x=r\cos( kt)$, $y=-r\sin(kt)$.

If at time $0$ we are at some other point $P$ on the circle, find an angle $\theta$ such that $P=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Then the parametric equation for counterclockwise travel is $x=r\cos(kt+\theta)$, $y=r\sin(kt+\theta)$. For clockwise, a manipulation similar to the one above gives
$$x=r\cos( kt-\theta), \qquad y=-r\sin(kt-\theta).$$
In your particular case, we have $\theta=0$.

One can generalize the above to travelling around a circle with centre $(a,b)$.